# Tikz QTree gradient edges in exam choices

Tags: exam, tikz-qtree

Tikz is drawing some (vertical) QTree edges with a gradient in an exam.  I'm finding that these happen only when the tikzpicture is part of a choice and when it's not centered.

For example, this repeats the figure three times, but only the middle instance has the gradient edge:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzstyle{impTreePos} = [draw,circle, fill,inner sep=2pt]
  
%tikz command to set up impartial trees (using tikz-qtree package)
\newcommand{\impartialTreeTikzStyling}{%
  %\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle]
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
     edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-8pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
}

\newcommand{\drawSampleTree}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
        \tikzset{sibling distance=15pt}
        \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, impTreePos}}
        
        \impartialTreeTikzStyling
        
        \Tree 
        [.{}
            [.{} ]]
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\drawSampleTree %no gradient

\begin{questions}
            
\question

Question

\begin{choices}
\choice 
\drawSampleTree %gradient!!!!!!!

\choice 
\begin{center}\drawSampleTree\end{center} %no gradient
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Middle figure has gradient edge]

I don't want these gradient edges.  What should I do so that they are solid?

Comment: It's not clear how to compile your example without a document class. Which are you using? (If `exam.cls` is it the one installed in TL/MikTeX, the other one on CTAN or another?)

Comment: @cfr Oops!  It's the one on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en

Comment: When I add the class and compile your code, I get three more-or-less indistinguishable trees. No sign of any gradient effect in any of them. Can you check if you see the problem compiling your code in a clean `.tex` file? Do you still see the problem if you zoom in? Which compiler are you using? (I tested with pdfTeX.)

Comment: I compiled it again today and no longer see the gradient edge, just like you said.

Comment: Maybe a pdf viewer issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same code no longer causes a gradient edge.  (This is compiled on a different computer than when the question was asked a year ago.)

`````
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzstyle{impTreePos} = [draw,circle, fill,inner sep=2pt]
  
%tikz command to set up impartial trees (using tikz-qtree package)
\newcommand{\impartialTreeTikzStyling}{%
  %\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle]
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
     edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-8pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
}

\newcommand{\drawSampleTree}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{level distance=30pt}
        \tikzset{sibling distance=15pt}
        \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, impTreePos}}
        
        \impartialTreeTikzStyling
        
        \Tree 
        [.{}
            [.{} ]]
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\drawSampleTree %no gradient

\begin{questions}
            
\question

Question

\begin{choices}
\choice 
\drawSampleTree %no gradient

\choice 
\begin{center}\drawSampleTree\end{center} %no gradient
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
\end{document}````
`````